# Python DNA sequence slice gives \N as wrong content in slice result

Tags: python, sequence, slice

I am surprising, I am using python to slice a long DNA Sequence (4699673 character)to a specific length supstring, it's working properly with a problem in result, after 71 good result \n start apear in result for few slices then correct slices again and so on for whole long file

the code:

```
import sys
filename  = open("out_filePU.txt",'w')
sys.stdout = filename

my_file = open("GCF_000005845.2_ASM584v2_genomic_edited.fna")
st = my_file.read()
length = len(st)
print ( 'Sequence Length is, :' ,length)
for i in range(0,len(st[:-9])):
print(st[i:i+9], i)
```

[figure shows the error from the result file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soZWG.png)

please i need advice on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sequence file contains multiple lines, and at the end of each line there is a line break `\n`. You can remove them with `st = my_file.read().replace("\n", "")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `st = re.sub('\\s', '', my_file.read())` to replace any newlines or other whitespace (you'll need to add `import re` at the top of your script).

Then `for i in range(0,len(st[:-9]),9):` to step through your data in increments of nine characters. Otherwise you're only advancing by one character each time: that's why you can see the diagonal patterns in your output.

[image]